# Hide the selected DropdownItem's text in the DropdownButton and only display the icon

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dropdown

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

I have created a `DropdownButton` with two `DropdownItem`s (share and edit). Whenever I select a `DropdownItem` (for example edit as you can see in pic 2), the selected item's value gets displayed (pic 2). I don't this to happen. I just want to display the icon (in my case the info icon) even when a `DropdownItem` is selected).

I tried various things like setting `isDense` to true or wrapping the `DropdownButton` with a `SizedBox` and setting some `width` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a popupmenubutton.